# Hibernate custom sql query for one-to-one?

Tags: hibernate, orm

I'm trying to map a one-to-one association.

My DB is like this:

```
CONTACT                         CONTACTPHONE
PK CONTACT_ID ---------|        PK CONTACTPHONE_ID
                       ---------FK CONTACT_ID
                                FK PHONETYPE_ID
```

As you can see, it's a one-to-many relationship, though there's a unique constraint between contact_id and phonetype_id, which prevents two of the same phone numbers to be entered (i.e. only one Cell phone number per contact).

I'm trying to map one of these numbers (Direct, which is when phonetype_id = 1001) to a directPhone property in the contact.

Is this possible??

(Reason I need to do this is because I need to load large lists of contacts (20-50) with a directPhone already initialized, instead of running an additional 20-50 queries to get the directPhone per contact...